# La consola nunca para de pedirme valores. Bucle While, C++

Tags: c++, string, while

Hola buenas quiero realizar un código en donde la consola pida introducir una serie de strings, para después organizarlo en una pila y leerlos en orden inverso.
Mi problema creo está en el primer bucle while.

Ya que nunca para de perdime palabras.

Un saludo.

```
//Fichero: stringPila.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>

int main() {
    // Declaro la pila
    std::stack<std::string> pila;
    std::string palabra;

    //Aqui meto las palabras
    while (std::cin >> palabra) { // ¿Posible fallo?
        pila.push(palabra);
    }

   
    while (!pila.empty()) {
       std::cout << pila.top() << std::endl;
       pila.pop();    
       }
    return 0;
}//end main
```

Comment: pon un `break;`

Comment: Para indicar que la entrada de `stdin` termino tienes que enviar un `EOF`. Si estas en linux en una nueva linea tienes que presionar `Ctrl-D` y darle enter. En Windows igual pero con `Ctrl-Z`.

Comment: No sabía lo de Ctrl-Z. Funciona perfecto. Gracias.

Answer (score -1):

El while tendrias que poder terminarlo de alguna forma, por que lo que tienes es un loop infinito. con un if antes del pila.push(palabra); ahi validas si la palabra es una cadena nula o vacia y rompes el while con un break;

Comment: Es una solución válida. Gracias por la aportación.

Comment: El código se responde con código. Una descripción, aunque válida y correcta, probablemente será mal entendida y peor implementada. Lo mejor es tomar el código original, corregirlo y ponerlo en la respuesta.

Comment: @AlexHernzandezGarcia, re recomiendo editar tu respuesta y completarla añadiendo el código de la pregunta e implementando en él tu respuesta con la explicación que has puesto o tu respuesta corre el riesgo de ser eliinada. Un saludo